# Can I use Webpack Module Federation plugin with create-react-app directly without ejecting

Tags: javascript, webpack, create-react-app, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

Can I use Webpack Module Federation plugin to convert my existing create-react-app directly without ejecting and without using CRACO configs ?

Answer (score 1):

Considering you can't modify the Webpack configuration in an un-ejected, non-CRACO `react-scripts` (`create-react-app`): I don't think so.